# Best partitioning guide?

Tags: partitioning

I really apologize to all of the users as I'm sure you are tired of seeing partitioning threads. But I got myself into an interesting situation. After figuring out I had to turn off some features on my MSI GE60 Apache pro to properly get the usb install process going. I attempted to install Ubuntu.

Unfortunately, I was tired and wanted to get this done to setup android studio and start developing. This led me to select the most basic features and try to install Ubuntu on my SSD which I didn't wanted too. Now the installation only got through partially since it didn't have enough space. Afterwards I noticed that I can't use Ubuntu, but apparently a partition from my C disk (SSD) was still made.

I then tried to uninstall it and properly do it on my 1TB HDD. For some reason it won't uninstall it until I go through the entire setup process, but I also messed that up as I just made 15 GB of unalocated space on the HDD.

So before I keep messing up could anyone help me on how to revert these changes and properly do the partition for Ubuntu?

There are so many tutorials that I don't know which one would be the most reliable one.

Comment: Is that MSI a newer UEFI/gpt system or a BIOS/MBR system? Partitioning needs to be different depending. But basic Ubuntu partitions are otherwise the same. Default install is / (root) & swap. But better to add either /home or data partition(s) or both.  But a lot depends on how you will use system. A new user is usually ok with just / & swap,  but a full drive install should not be just / as then parts of system are scattered across entire drive. Better then to just use 25GB for /. http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Thank you for the help. I just got it to work. I seem to have two versions so my SSD disk (even after freeing up the partition) seems to still have ubuntu. I'll try to figure out over time.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

At the fourth step, select "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu", assuming you wish to wipe the entire 1TB disk and install Ubuntu to it. Use the drop-down menu to select which drive you wish to install Ubuntu to. At that point, you can go ahead and press "Install Now" and continue following the steps for installation through the guide I linked.

Additionally, if you'd like to wipe the SSD, you can do so after you install Ubuntu. Use the Ctrl-Alt-T sequence to open up a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Once it is finished, open the newly installed GParted application. Select the device you wish to format using the menu in the top-right hand corner of the application. When you are done formatting the device, select the "Accept" button on the menu bar to save your changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference to follow! I actually don't want to erase either drive completely as I have files I need on both. I simply want to restore the space on the SSD and then restore the unallocated space I took from the 1TB and add to it to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Ahh ok. Then in that case, you can boot Ubuntu as a live CD and then use GParted or the Disk Utility (it may be called Disks) and create a new partition that includes the unallocated space, whilst also keeping your data. Take a look [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html) for some tips on using GParted. If possible, it is probably easiest if you save the data on the disks externally to prevent any potential screw-ups deleting your data.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I just got it to work. I seem to have two versions so my SSD disk (even after freeing up the partition) seems to still have ubuntu. I'll try to figure out over time.